# jQuery autocomplete remote solr data source and custom data as html issue

Tags: jquery, solr

Hi i have the search application which having search suggestion textbox(basically autocomplete),

the UI autocomplete data are come from remote solr host .i can able to get the data and display it in the dropdown list without any problem.

The problem is i want to format my dropdown list into html custom data. so that it will display the user's image with some info.

my code is  as follows :

```
$( "#user" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://mysolrhot:port/?json.wrg=?",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        q: request.term,
        wt: "json",
        Rows: 12,
        start:0,
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response(
          $.map(data.reponse.docs, function(item) {
            return {
              label: item.name+ 
              value: item.name
            }
          })
        );
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {

  }
});
```

The above code displayed only text information in the UI dropdown. Here i want the custom html output. For the i have tried with following code

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

  return $("<li><li>")
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( "<a>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.country + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );

};
```

and i commended the response() block on success function() in the above auto complete. because  ._renderItem will going to handle the dropdown list.

The problem is when i start typing in the text box nothing will happen.the request made successfully but dropdown will not come. in the javascript console their is no error also.

Jquery i used as follows :

```
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

can any plz help  what is the error here .if version is the problem. pls let me know the working version...plz help me to come out from this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recent demo autocomplete from Solr that I built, I used [jquery.autocomplete.html.js](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js) which supports passing arbitrary html for the autocomplete label.

Here's roughly how that looks (in CoffeeScript) in my app: https://github.com/onemorecloud/demo-rails-jquery-rsolr-address-autocomplete/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/addresses.js.coffee

```
$ ->

  $('input[type="search"]').autocomplete

    delay: 0
    html: true

    source: (request, response) ->

      $.getJSON "/autocomplete?q=#{request.term}", (data) ->

        suggestions = []

        $.each data.response.docs, (i, doc) ->

          label = # create a HTML label using doc, a Solr response document
          value = # create a text-field value for the selected document

          suggestions.push(
            label: label,
            value: value
          )

        response suggestions
```

You could do something similar, just concatenate whatever you need into that `label` variable.

Comment: let me do that and let you know

Comment: can plz suggest me .... how should implemnet this... i assume i have include address.js.coffee into my application view rite?

Comment: the essential difference is the jquery.autocomplete.html.js, you should read its docs. it provides the `html: true` option which lets you specify arbitrary html for the `label`. your code is close enough that you should be able to adapt it from there.